# Using \noindent in \AfterEndEnvironment from etoolbox creates bigger gaps between two environments

Tags: indentation, etoolbox, vspace

Using `\noindent` in `\AfterEndEnvironment` from `etoolbox` creates bigger gaps between two environments than it should. Here is code, that fully describes the problem.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{Th}{Theorem}
\AfterEndEnvironment{Th}{\noindent\ignorespaces}
\AfterEndEnvironment{proof}{\noindent\ignorespaces}
\begin{document}
\begin{Th}
This is just some theorem. This is just some theorem. This is just some theorem.
This is just some theorem. This is just some theorem. This is just some theorem.
This is just some theorem. This is just some theorem.
\end{Th}
\begin{proof}
This is just some proof. Note that the gap between the upper Theorem and this
proof is quite recognizable. It should not be this big. This is just some proof.
This is just some proof. This is just some proof. This is just some proof. 
\end{proof}
Now in contrast to the gap above, the gap bewteen an environment and plain text
seems to be normal. How can I reduce the gap between two environments without
hurting the correct gap between environments and plain text?
\end{document}
```

Also, here is a picture of what the pdf looks like:
[image: A picture of the pdf]

If I remove the `\AfterEndEnvoronment` stuff, the distance bewteen the Theorem and the Proof indeed gets smaller.

Can someone help? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LaTeX has a built in mechanism to suppress the indent of paragraphs following an environment. This mechanism can be used by setting `\@endpetrue` inside the environment, however `amsthm` uses code to always set `\@endpefalse` at the end of the theorem environments (the underlying environment used by `amsthm` would normally use that mechanism).

Hence the easiest way to do this is to remove the `\@endpefalse` from your environment.

Afterwards what you get is basically the behaviour of the list-like environments, if you put a blank line after `\end{Th}` you'll get an indented paragraph. If you omit the blank line the following paragraph isn't indented.

Note however, that from a semantic view point, at the end of a proof or theorem there should be a new paragraph, and hence there should be indentation. Anyways, the following does what you're asking:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{Th}{Theorem}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\endproof}{\@endpefalse}{}{}
\patchcmd{\endTh}{\@endpefalse}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{Th}
This is just some theorem. This is just some theorem. This is just some theorem.
This is just some theorem. This is just some theorem. This is just some theorem.
This is just some theorem. This is just some theorem.
\end{Th}
\begin{proof}
This is just some proof. Note that the gap between the upper Theorem and this
proof is quite recognizable. It should not be this big. This is just some proof.
This is just some proof. This is just some proof. This is just some proof. 
\end{proof}
Now in contrast to the gap above, the gap bewteen an environment and plain text
seems to be normal. How can I reduce the gap between two environments without
hurting the correct gap between environments and plain text?
\end{document}
```

[image]